# Spring MVC XML + Java configuration issue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In my Spring MVC project all mvc configuration is done using XML.

Now I'm trying to integrate Spring security and adding **annotation** based security configuration (`@EnableWebScurity` & `@Configuration`) extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Is it possible?

My Problem:

Whenever I try to take any autowired dependency in my `@EnableWebMvc` class, `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.crud.servicesimpl.UserServiceImpl]`

**Code snippets:**

SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;
```

Service class:

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.crud.services.UserService] found for dependency [com.crud.services.UserService]: expected at least 1
```

Comment: Program to interfaces instead of concrete classes. You should propably inject a `UserDetailsService` .

Comment: @M.Deinum thank you. Earlier I tried to inject UserDetailsService also. but facing the same problem. That's why tried the one as mentioned in the code.

Comment: You want `UserService` ( I assumed you extended the Spring Security base classes) not `UserDetailsService` or `UserServiceImpl`. Again program to interface that is why you define those in the first place to have a contract to use and program against.

Answer (score 0):

try to add in your xml config: `<context:component-scanbase-package="...">` and
`<context:annotation-config>`
best regards

Answer (score 0):

Add @ComponentScan(basePackages={"add you package name here"})

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.crud"})
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
     UserService userService;
}
```

Also add  in your xml file.

Comment: @ComponentScan works, but does it override my XML configuration? Because after adding it, `No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]` exception is raised, as my SessionFactory bean is configured in xml conf file.

Comment: Can you tell me the package name where you have configured session factory?

Comment: You also need to add <context:annotation-config> in your xml file as well. I have edited my answer.

Comment: SessionFactory is configured in spring-servlet.xml which is inside WEB-INF folder. It was working fine before adding @ComponentScan in java conf class. Also all basic stuff are already done like: `<context:annotation-config /> <context:component-scan base-package="com.crud" /> <mvc:annotation-driven />`

Comment: Can you share your spring-servlet.xml?